# docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for *.qa.npsdev.cloud, not registry-1.docker.io

Tags: docker

Im trying to run `sudo docker run ubuntu` and it returns `Unable to find image 'plex:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for *.qa.npsdev.cloud, not registry-1.docker.io. See 'docker run --help'.`

Can anyone help me please? I've been debuging for 2 days.

Comment: Someone is hijacking your connection to docker Hub and sending it to some qa server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.